# Shapefiles source set-up everytime in mxd ArcMap project?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-source

I have a **folder** where there is an (mxd file + another folder containing some shapefiles I work on). I am exchanging this **folder** with a group of users. We work together on a project, and everytime a user wants to open it he gets those red exclamation marks and has to set-up a new shapefile source.

Is there a way to make ArcMap recognise automatically this source ?

It's becoming frustrating to change the source every time.

Comment: Hi Liana, welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please [take the Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: What version are you using? In 10.x, within the MXD itself, under File | Properties, there is an option to store relative pathnames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the relative path names option: 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm#GUID-5118AC85-57E4-4027-AC24-FB6E99FADEFF

By ticking the box to store relative paths ArcMap will remember the location of the ShapeFiles within the folder you're sharing, even if that folder has moved to a different computer.

It can be found:

**File > Map Document Properties**